# Behaviour of the solutions of a system of differential equations at infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, lyapunov-functions

Consider the following system of differential equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
u'=-u+uv\\
v'=-2v-u^2
\end{cases}
$$

I'm able to prove that solutions must tend to $0$ if $t\to 0$ by the use of Lyapunov function $L(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ but I'm unable to prove that the function:
$$
I(t)=\frac{x^2(t)+2y^2(t)}{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}
$$

must admit limit for $t\to+\infty$

Any hint for a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mmh… Have you tried to compute the time derivative of $I$? You should first check that it actually goes to zero (it probably has to, if you want to prove existence of a limit). Then maybe you manage to find some additional properties of the derivative; for instance, it could be positive or negative, so that $I$ is monotone and admits a limit. Or maybe you can estimate the decay at infinity of the derivative in such a way that you can integrate it on $[0,+\infty)$ (e.g., if the decay of the derivative at $0$ is exponential, then $I$ admits a limit).

Comment: Small note: for all times you have $1\leq I(t)\leq 2$. This is trivial, but it might be useful to have in mind.

Comment: Unfortunatly, unless my calculations are completely wrong, the first derivative has no fixed sign.

Comment: In the system of first order ordinary differential equations you the variables $u$ and $v$. But in all other equation you use $x$ and $y$. How do you combine the two? Are you using $x=u$ and $y=v$?

Comment: That “$t\to0$” should be $t \to \infty$?

Comment: Thanks to @KwinvanderVeen,HansLundmark for findind the misprints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compute the time derivative of $I$, you obtain
$$I’(t)=-\frac{2x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}+\frac{-2x^2y^3-4x^4y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$
The idea is that the first part is negative, while the second part goes to zero exponentially.

More precisely, integrating the above equality in the time variable from $0$ to $t$, you have
$$I(t)=I(0)+f(t)+g(t),$$
where
$$f(t)=\int_0^t -\frac{2x^2 (s) y^2 (s)}{(x^2 (s) +y^2 (s))^2} ds$$
is a non-increasing function, and
$$g(t)= \int_0^t -\frac{-2x^2 (s) y^3 (s)-4x^4 (s) y (s)}{(x^2 (s) +y^2 (s))^2} ds$$
is such that $g(t)$ converges to some finite value for $x\to+\infty$ thanks to the exponential decay of the integrand (see below).

This means that both functions admit limits, hence $I$ admits a limit. In principle, the limit of $f$ might be infinite, but then you can use the fact that $1\leq I(t)\leq 2$ to conclude that the limit is finite.

---

Concerning the exponential decay of the integrand of $g$, this essentially follows from the calculations you did for the Lyapunov functions. In particular, you have
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(x^2(t)+y^2(t))=-x^2(t)-2y^2(t)\leq -x^2(t)-y^2(t).$$
By Gronwall’s lemma, you have
$$(x^2(t)+y^2(t))\leq (x^2(0)+y^2(0))e^{-2t}.$$
Now you can use the algebraic inequalities
$$\left|\frac{-2x^2y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\leq 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$
$$\left|\frac{-4x^4y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\leq 4\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
to conclude that the integrand of $g$ goes to zero at lest as $e^{-t}$.

---

There is another, more standard proof which uses a bootstrap argument to show that $x(t)\sim e^{-t}$ if $x(0)\neq 0$ and $|y(t)|\leq C(1+t)e^{-2t}$. If you prove this, it’s easy to show that if $x(0)=0$ you have $I\equiv 2$, while if $x(0)\neq 0$ you have $I(t)\to 1$.

The first step for the proof would be to make a change of variables $X=e^{t}x$, $Y=e^{2t}y$, so that the system becomes
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&X’=e^{-2t}XY\\&Y’=-X^2\end{aligned}\right.. $$

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The Lyapunov function allows one to conclude that the origin is asymptotically stable. Therefore, eventually one can approximate the dynamics with the dynamics linearized at the origin, which gives

\begin{cases}
u'=-u \\
v'=-2v
\end{cases}

from which one can see that $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ can eventually be approximated with $e^{-t} C_1$ and $e^{-2t} C_2$ respectively. One could substitute these expressions in the expression for $I(t)$ and find it's limit as $t\to\infty$ or use that $e^{-2t}$ goes faster to zero than $e^{-t}$ directly.

---

It can also be noted that the sign analysis approach of the time derivative of $I(t)$ might give inconclusive results. For example consider the following system

\begin{cases}
x' = -2\,x + x\,z - y\,z \\
y' = -y + x\,z - z^2 \\
z' = -3\,z - x^2 + y\,z
\end{cases}

for which it can also be shown to be asymptotically stable using the Lyapunov function $V(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.

The limiting behavior as $t\to\infty$ of

$$
I(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2 + 2\,y^2 + 3\,z^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}
$$

will probably be inconclusive when looking at the time derivative of $I(x,y,z)$. But using the linearization one can say that it will go to $2$ for most initial conditions.

Comment: I was thinking about that same thing, but I don’t find rigorous to say that $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ eventually behave like the solutions to the linearized system. It is actually not even true that $v(t)$ behaves like $e^{-2t}C$: the exact behaviour of $v(t)$ is $te^{-2t}C$ for large times, meaning that their ratio goes to $1$ for some constant $C$ (for most initial data). So, it doesn’t seem right to me to say that the solutions behave like the ones of the linearized system just because of the asymptotic stability (even though the intuition is essentially correct and eventually leads to the result).

Comment: A better example for what I want to say: if instead we had the equations $u’=-u+uv$, $v’=-3v-u^2$, $v(t)$ would probably still behave not better than $e^{-2t}$, due to the factor $u^2$ on the RHS that has that asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: @Lorenzo Pompili ah yes, you are correct. I initially overlooked that, just saw that the linearization equilibrium at the equilibrium point didn't had eigenvalues on the imaginary axis and thought "great, now I can use the linearization itself directly". Though, this doesn't change the conclusion, since $t\,e^{-2\,t}$ still goes to zero faster than $e^{-t}$. But due to this my approach would not give a rigorous enough proof.

Comment: Although, I do suspect that one could show that in most cases only looking at the linearization would be sufficient as long as all the eigenvalues are different, because eventually the polynomials don't matter and only the slowest exponential decay rates does. The only counter argument to this I could think off is having some nonlinearity, sufficiently far enough away from the origin, that drives the "slow" state already to zero in finite time before.